# Using User Defined Table Types as Sproc Parameters in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does the current version of EF support user defined table types for Insert, Update and Delete methods on Entities?

I would like to use this feature so I don't have to pass in every column name to my sproc.  I am not sure if EF can support one Sproc that would do all the updates for an entity though.

Answer (score 5):

Table valued parameters are not supported but you can vote for them in [UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015347-table-valued-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out.  When I tried to import the sproc into my model I get this error message:

> The function 'MySproc' has a parameter 'MyTableValuedParameter' at parameter index 0 that has a data type 'table type' which is not supported. The function was excluded.

So it would seem that the answer is no.  They are not supported in Entity Framework.